# Is a Django/React/WebGL a bad stack for web based game with community features around it?

Tags: python, django, reactjs

I have started a project for my own education (and profit if it becomes a viable product), which is a web based strategy game. I am building all the server side game logic in python, and I am planning on learning Django and React to use in the front end, with WebGL for the actual game graphics.

The reason I want to use a large framework like Django is because I plan on building a community around the game with forums and chat for people to share strategies, etc. There will also be leader boards and that kind of thing as well, so I need something that will be able to handle security and other things.

The game will be 3D but it's turn based so the network connection to the server side game engine isn't super critical. Nevertheless, I am wondering if passing my game events to the server through Django is a bad idea.

Could anyone with more experience with this stack enlighten me?

Comment: It completely depends on what your product does. If it requires constant real-time updates (think FPS) then probably not, you'll want something with websockets. If it's saving a score at the end of a level, slow paced turns, or other less frequent stuff then maybe. The fact that it's 3D is irrelevant, as all 3D processing is done o n the client - not the server.

Comment: @Shadow As I said in my post it is a turn based game. Each turn, the players will be able to make their ships do things like move, shoot, etc, so it will be pretty slow paced in terms of updates being sent.

Comment: In that case, my advice is to simply try it. If you design your database well (which is probably more important than how you use it!) then you can always change backends.